# adding multiple object values in a RDF triple

Tags: rdf, n3

I need to add an OR condition in place of just "Female" i.e., a single value. Like it should be "Female" || "female". Basically I want to make it case insensitive so that this condition matches with both values be it written small or capital letters.

```
# N3 rule if person gender is female
{
    ?person :gender  "Female".
}
=>
{
    ?person :gender_id 442986. # Female Id
}.
```

Comment: If a rule language doesn't support `n`-ary union operator in the premise, a common workaround is to use `n` rules with the same conclusion. This is logically the same.